# Create shareable VM image that runs specific application

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to create a VM image that contains a single application and all of its dependencies that I can package and send to another developer. This developer could then take this image and stand up a VM that contains my application and run it the same way I would without having to do any additional installation. I know Docker provides functionality similar to this but my application depends on CentOS 6 so I don't think Docker is an option for me. Is building such a VM image possible? I am currently using VirtualBox but I would be open to using something else.

Comment: Have you tried just sharing the VM files with this other developer? You could go to `File > Export Appliance`.

Comment: If by files you mean the application files then yes. However, they regularly run into issues building and running the application that I never see despite having built the application on several different machines. This makes it hard for me to help them debug and thus slows down our progress. I'm hoping that by building the application myself and then sending it to them we can save time

Comment: No, I meant your VM files. Your entire pre-built VM.

Comment: Didn't see your edit. Would this create an iso image that they can then use? If so, I was not aware of this option and I will def try that.

Comment: It should create an `*.ova` image that they can import into VirtualBox on their end. I've never done this, however.

Comment: I will give that a try and post my results.